# Heroku Fail: Doesn't Recognize Ghost Blog Assets

Tags: heroku, handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I've updated my blog to ghost-0.5.7, and am trying to get the [creator theme](http://phantomus.com/features#themes) to work. But I'm running into an error on Heroku that I don't know how to fix. I've already posted on the Ghost Blog forum, but the creators of the blog can't seem to help. Any thoughts? Here's the directory structure and the heroku log:

```
├── LICENSE
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── foundation.css
│   │   ├── icons
│   │   │   ├── default
│   │   │   │   ├── default_logo_no_title_275x50.png
│   │   │   │   └── default_logo_no_title_275x50_2x.png
│   │   │   └── load
│   │   │   └── load.gif
│   │   ├── normalize.css
│   │   └── screen.css
│   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── icon-font.eot
│   │   ├── icon-font.svg
│   │   ├── icon-font.ttf
│   │   └── icon-font.woff
│   └── js
│   ├── index.js
│   └── jquery.fitvids.js
├── default.hbs
├── index.hbs
├── package.json
├── page.hbs
├── partials
│   ├── backfrompost.hbs
│   ├── header.hbs
│   └── pagination.hbs
└── post.hbs`

2014-12-23T07:25:46.863433+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR: [default.hbs] The partial header could not be found
2014-12-23T07:25:46.863438+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: The partial header could not be found
2014-12-23T07:25:46.863440+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Error ()
2014-12-23T07:25:46.863441+00:00 app[web.1]: at Error.Exception (/app/node_modules/express-hbs/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/exception.js:13:41)
2014-12-23T07:25:46.863443+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.invokePartial (/app/node_modules/express-hbs/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:179:11)
2014-12-23T07:25:46.863445+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.invokePartialWrapper as invokePartial
2014-12-23T07:25:46.863436+00:00 app[web.1]: Ghost caught a processing error in the middleware layer. 
2014-12-23T07:25:46.863427+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-12-23T07:25:46.863447+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.eval (eval at (/app/node_modules/express-hbs/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/javascript-compiler.js:171:23), :17:17)
2014-12-23T07:25:46.863434+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendering Error Page 
2014-12-23T07:25:46.863449+00:00 app[web.1]: at ret (/app/node_modules/express-hbs/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:137:30)
2014-12-23T07:25:46.863451+00:00 app[web.1]: at ret (/app/node_modules/express-hbs/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js:422:21)
2014-12-23T07:25:46.863470+00:00 app[web.1]: at renderTemplate (/app/node_modules/express-hbs/lib/hbs.js:385:13)
2014-12-23T07:25:46.863472+00:00 app[web.1]: at stackRenderer (/app/node_modules/express-hbs/lib/hbs.js:426:9)
2014-12-23T07:25:46.863473+00:00 app[web.1]: at Waiter.callback (/app/nodemodules/express-hbs/lib/hbs.js:405:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is a solution, but I realized that I think I may have had some old files/configuration/etc. lingering in my Heroku app from a previous push.

So, I decided to (1) `git reset --hard`, then (2) push the repo again. It's working now!